# How to see the call stack of the functions being called in a page

Tags: 7

I am beginning to work on a project that has quite a few modules(around 20) which I am not really familiar with. Is there a tool or suggestion, besides dpm-ing the function name, to detect the functions and modules being used in a random page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the complete callstack of the functions being called, you should set up a debugging environment for doing so.

The quickest way to do is by downloading the [Quickstart: Prebuilt Drupal Development Environment](https://drupal.org/project/quickstart), which is a virtual machine copy of preconfigured ubuntu. The netbeans IDE is configured for debugging the Drupal code. It also has an display to look at the callstack at the bottom of the IDE, when in debug mode.

> What all is included in it:
>
> - Support for Drupal 7 and Drupal 6
> - Ubuntu Linux, Apache, MySQL, APC, XDebug, IMAP, UploadProgress
> - Firefox (with developer plugins) and Chrome
> - Drush, drush make, and custom drush commands
> - Install scripts for: Apache Solr, Aegir, Hudson, and Oracle
> - Netbeans and Eclipse, configured with XDebug
> - XHProf and Webgrind profilers. Emails logged as files
> - cvs, subversion, git, bazaar

You can have a look at its [dedicated youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/drupalquickstart) for helpful screencasts.